# Example of custom event dispatching in Android?

Tags: android, events, listener, dispatch

I have a scenario below, and was wondering if anyone had a good solution. Basically, I have a class which manages a custom ViewFlipper object. One of these views within the ViewFlipper instance consists of a custom ScrollView with custom rows (which reside in *mRows* an ArrayList of the rows). In the custom ScrollView class I have the loop...

```
    for (CustomRow : mRows)
    { 
        row.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
```

In the onTouch listener I want to be able to notify the top level view (the object that holds the reference to the ViewFlipper instance). What is the most efficient way to do this?